# How can I prove that $X$ is locally compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ Hausdorff space. If for all compact $K\subset X$ and for all $U\supset K$ open exist $V$ open such that $\overline{V}$ is compact and $K\subset V\subset\overline{V}\subset U$, then X is locally compact.

This is my try:

Let $x\in X$ and $K\subset X$ compact. Then $x\in K$ or $x\in X\setminus K$.

Case 1: If $x\in K$ we are done, by hipothesis, every $U\supset K$ open is a nbhood for $x$, then exist $V$ open such that $\overline{V}$ is compact. Right?

Case 2: $x\in X\setminus K$. Since $X\setminus K$ is open, then... what happend?

Comment: Why not just take $K=\{x\}$?

Comment: $K=\{x\}$ is closed since $X$ is Hausdorff, but, is compact?

Comment: Does every open covering have a finite subcovering? (yes)

Comment: Which definition of locally compact do you use?